# How solve null poinuter NullPointerException in java.lang.String org.jsoup.nodes.Element.ownText()

Tags: android, jsoup

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.jsoup.nodes.Element.ownText()' on a null object reference
```

Here is My Code:

```
public class VersionChecker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String newVersion;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get()
                    .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
                    .first()
                    .ownText();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newVersion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: 'first()' is returning null which it can if prior 'select' produced no results (empty list).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this.( Not the right way around but just a temporary fix )

```
val versionUrl =
            "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + context.packageName + "&hl=en"
        latestVersion = Jsoup.connect(versionUrl)
            .timeout(30000)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
            .referrer("http://www.google.com")
            .get()
            .html()
            .replaceAfter("<!", "")
            .replace("<!", "")
```

Answer (score -1):

Android playstore updated their UI, so trying to select the current version from the unparsed html is returning null cause it no longer exists. [The "version" tag we parsed for now exists inside this popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLYsO.png)

I'll suggest an alternative:

You'll have to choose a different method of detecting an update, I'd recommend checking the in-app API from Android.

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#groovy

1. You'll just need to add the dependency and resync gradle files:

implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.0.0'

2. Implement the AppUpdateManger snippet available in the doc linked above, i've wrapped mine in a method that returns a boolean as to if an update is available or not:

   ```
   public boolean isUpdateAvailable() {

       AtomicReference<Boolean> isUpdateAvailable = new AtomicReference<>(false);
       AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context);

       // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
       Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

       // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
       appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {

           /** UpdateAvailability
            * int UNKNOWN = 0;
            * int UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE = 1;
            * int UPDATE_AVAILABLE = 2;
            * int DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS = 3;
            * */

           if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {
               isUpdateAvailable.set(true);
           }
       });

       return isUpdateAvailable.get();
   }
   ```

Comment: Pls share such info in comments and not answers. Answers are only used when you have a solution to the problem. Comments can be used for clarification or telling such info.